# CORS issue while using Azure AD SSO

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service

I have an AngularJS application with Spring REST back-end. Now it is desired that Azure AD with SAML SSO is added to the mix. Somebody has already added OpenSAML library for the Spring REST back-end. AngularJS using $http service is making a call to some endpoint of Spring REST back-end which in turn makes AuthnRequest built using OpenSAML to Azure IDP which gets blocked by CORS policy.How to overcome  this? My app is registered with Azure Active Directory, but it is not deployed with  Azure. Do I have to do anything at the Azure end? I cannot redirect from my spring server. I can however redirect from client using $window.location.href but then response object is lost.I can use nested get calls on $http, but then also encounter CORS issue.

Comment: What I would do is instead use OAuth implicit grant flow on front-end and use JSON Web Token authentication in back-end. Why is SAML required?

Comment: @juunas, somebody else took the decision & we have to live with at. We had a .NET based web application which used SAML for SSO in Azure AD Connect - though I do not have access to the code. Now for the mobile app in place of .NET we are using java.

Comment: No idea, sorry :/